# Override setter for `var` inherited from trait

Tags: scala

How in Scala I can override setter for `var` defined in base trait? This code seems doesn't work for me:

```
trait A {
  var value: Int = _
}


class B extends A {
  def value_(newValue: Int) = { 
    value = newValue
    //other logic 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't override a `var` with anything other than another `var`.  You can *implement* a `var` with a getter/setter pair, but not override one.  So this works:

```
trait A { var value: Int }
class B extends A {
  def value = 5
  def value_=(v: Int) { println(s"You like $v, but I like 5.") }
}
```

If you can't modify the trait, you're in a bit of a bind--it's part of the API of the trait, effectively, that you *can't* perform input validation on the value.

(It's arguably a bug or at least inconsistent that it works this way; if you have a `var` it makes some sense to make sure it is *just* a `var` for optimization reasons.  But then if the trait doesn't implement it itself, why should that matter?)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to Rex Kerr's answer that you can get around the limitation by explicitly if you can modify the trait by declaring the methods for accessing your variable explicitly, and there is no problem overriding them:

```
trait A {
  private[this] var _value: Int = _;
  def value: Int = _value;
  def value_=(v: Int) { _value = v; };
}


class B extends A {
  override def value_=(newValue: Int) = {
    super.value = newValue;
    //other logic
  }
}

class C extends A {
  override var value: Int = _;
}
```